# How to pass multiple structs as same parameter using void pointer through multiple levels

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

I have multiple structs I am trying to pass into the same parameter for a function using void pointers, but it is not working and I don't know why.

I created a simple test case to show what I'm running into. If I compile with clang in repl it works, but if I compile with gcc on Linux mint, I get nonsense for the second printf statement.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Test {
    char *name;
};

void *create();
void update(void *data);

struct Test *test_create();
void test_update(struct Test *test);

int main()
{
    void *currentData = create();

    update(currentData);

    return 0;
}

void *create()
{
    void *data = test_create();

    return data;
}

void update(void *data)
{
    struct Test *test = data;

    printf("a  %s\n", test->name);
    test_update(test);
}

struct Test *test_create()
{
    struct Test *test = &(struct Test) {
        .name = "test",
    };

    return test;
}

void test_update(struct Test *test)
{
    printf("b  %s\n", test->name);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What operation is undefined?

Comment: `test_create` creates `test` on the stack. You need to use `malloc` in that function.

Comment: So don't declare test in update? I switched the call to test_update((struct Test *)data) and it worked. But why does this work? Aren't they both pointers to the same thing?

Comment: My first comment was wrong so I deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `test_create`, you're creating a compound literal and returning a pointer to it.  The lifetime of a compound literal is that of its enclosing scope, so when the function returns you're returning a pointer to an object that no longer exists.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should instead allocate memory dynamically so it will live after the function returns.

```
struct Test *test_create()
{
    struct Test *test = malloc(sizeof *test);
    test->name = "test";

    return test;
}
```

Make sure to `free` this memory when it's no longer in use.